# Ruby, AWS SQS: how to get all the messages from a queue without removing them from the queue

Tags: ruby, amazon-sqs

How can I download all the messages in a SQS queue, but keeping them in the queue.

I need this for analysis purposes to not actually to execute the messages, this is because I need the messages to remain in the queue after my download.

Answer (score 3):

The AWS API allows you to download messages from the queue in batches of 10. The problem is that if you request the messages several times you may receive the same messages again.

The trick is to keep the downloaded messages hidden for subsequent requests, at less until you have downloaded all the messages. This has consequences, for example that the messages won't be accessible for other consumers either.

Example of code:

```
require "aws-sdk" # gem "aws-sdk", "~> 3"

client = Aws::SQS::Client.new(:region => "eu-west-1")
queue_url = "https://sqs.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/XXXX/your_queueu"

queue =
  Aws::SQS::Queue.new({
    :url => queue_url,
    :client => client
  })

loop do
  # [Aws::SQS::Queue.receive_messages documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/SQS/Queue.html#receive_messages-instance_method)
  messages =
    queue.receive_messages({
      :max_number_of_messages => 10,
      :visibility_timeout => 10 # make this as big as necessary to give time to the script to get all the Messages
    })

  messages.each do |message|
    # [Aws::SQS::Message documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/v3/api/Aws/SQS/Message.html)
    puts message.body # send the output to a file or where do you want
  end

  break if messages.length.zero?
end
```